# How can I initialize DataSpace.SSpace and DataSpace.CSpace generically?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, metadata

I'm creating a general-purpose EF model browser, where the model is loaded by selecting its DLL, then using reflection to instantiate the ObjectContext.

That part is working - the problem is operations that require DataSpace.SSpace and DataSpace.CSpace are failing and I'm trying to figure out how to get these initialized in a generic fashion so all my run-time EF utility metatadata query functions that use them will work.

Is there a way to initialize this metadata information while only having the DLL available (EDMX is not available).

Thanks in advance for any leads.

Comment: I think the way must exist, since LINQpad manages to do it. The CSDL and SSDL are resources in the DLL, right? I haven't connected all the dots, but is that getting you in the right direction? Worst case: Decompile LINQpad.

Comment: As you say, there is definitely a way to do it. (I had similar thoughts about LINQPad!) It's just that every metadata exploration example talks about how to use the metadata after it's already been initialized! Julie Lerman gave me a possible approach, and I'm working through the details on that now. I think I could be close. If I get it, I'll follow up with a blog post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Julie Lerman, Craig Stuntz, and Hadi Hariri, I was able to find a solution, using the syntax revealed in http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dd7b1c41-e428-4e29-ab83-448d3f529ba4/creating-an-entity-connection-from-a-sql-connection. It may not be optimal, but this works:

```
var workspace = new MetadataWorkspace(new string[] { "res://*/" }, 
    new Assembly[] { AssemblyContainingYourModel });
```

I also tried using MetadataWorkspace.LoadAssembly() but it resulted in:

```
The space 'OSpace' has no associated collection.
```